# Edit PDF from Google Drive

Tags: pdf, google-drive

I'm trying to use Google Drive to manage my PDF files. I want to edit them in my Android, possibly using Adobe Acrobat, and I need that as soon as the PDF editor saves the file Google Drive sync the new version of it. I'm using Android 6.0.1 and Drive 2.4.181.13.40 (wow)!

I have been doing that using Dropbox, and it just works. But it seems that Google Drive stops monitoring the file as soon as I open it using any other App. Can't I set Acrobat as a "PDF Editor" for Google Drive files?

Comment: If that is possible depends on the Google Drive app. In difference to Windows where every app can access all your files this is different on Android. Therefore it may be that Google Drive just sends the data to the PDF reader app and has no file to monitor...

Comment: Yeah, I remember when they've changed this permission thing. I do agree with you about this being a Google Drive matter... Even more because I just tried using Dropbox's "Open with..." and it works!

Comment: This has nothing to do with permissions. It is just how the developers implemented the call from Google Drive App to the PDF reader.